# Jquery code in table header partial randomly does not work when other custom js is on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

So I have a partial view that loads the table header. Inside the header there is the title and one of 3 dynamically shown buttons that when clicked open up a small div containing additional buttons. this jquery code works perfectly fine on pages without custom javascript/jquery inside of them. They also work 4 out of 5 times correctly on the pages with the custom code inisde of them.

*** updated with latest jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Use event delegation to handle clicks on the additional buttons
    $(document).on("click", "#@additionalButtonID, #@additionalButtonID2, #@additionalButtonID3", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event from propagating up to the document element
        const div = $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier");
        div.css("left", e.clientX -150);
        div.css("top", e.clientY);
        div.fadeIn(200);
    });

    // Use event delegation to handle clicks on the buttons inside the div
    $(document).on("click", "div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier button", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event from propagating up to the document element
        const div = $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier");
        div.fadeOut(200);
    });

    // Use event delegation to handle clicks on the li element
    $(document).on("click", ".list-tbl-items", function(e) {
       
 if ((e.target).querySelector('button') != null) {
        (e.target).querySelector('button').click();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

// Use event delegation to handle clicks on the document, outside of the div
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier").length) {
        const div = $("div#div-@Model.UniqueTableIdentifier");
        div.fadeOut(200);
    }
});
});
```

You see i even have the eventdelegation to go do onthe document click which i thought would just make it the header of the table at worst but still doing these issues. and worst is i can refresh the page multiple times before it happens again.

Comment: Can you add some additional debugging (to your code) - eg where *exactly* does it fail.  Do the events fire?  Add a console.log() inside every event.   Does it fail to find the selectors?  Add a `$(document).on("click", function() { console.log($("#@additionalButtonID").length) })` for every selector.

Comment: Please clarify on "*does not work*" - is there an error?  Nothing happens?  Check the console log.

Answer (score 0):

Probably jQuery script is still not loaded when you starts use it.
You should attach all events after page is loaded.
Using JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
  // here your code...
})
```

or using pure JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener ('load',()=>{
  // here your code...
} );
```

Comment: If jquery is not loaded, then what do you think `$(document)` will do?  *Yes* to wrap in doc.ready (generally), *no* to "jquery not loaded" - using event delegation means OP shouldn't need to wait for DOM ready (doc.ready), so that's unlikely the issue here.

Comment: When i put it in a document.ready some of the buttons dont click correctly in the menu i open and just leave the div menu open.

like the onlick event still hits and opens up what the button should do but it wont hit in my jquery and close the div.

Comment: Therefore there is pure JS option.

Comment: Using that didnt even cause the first click to work.

Comment: If you want to do it professionally, you should implement something that will let the user know that the page is not fully loaded.  Second way is not to use jQuery.
Becides it, try to determine why jQuery is loading so long...

Comment: To re-iterate: this has nothing to do with "why jquery is taking so long to load" - if jquery has not loaded yet (there's no "partially loaded" so "not fully loaded" = "not loaded") then the line `$(document)` will give an error.  jQuery has loaded at the point OPs code runs (unless their error *is* that jquery is not loaded, which is unclear as they've just stated "does not work")

Comment: therefore better is `window.addEventListener`